# Facebook Graph API: querying /me/photos works fine, but /me/photos?limit=100 returns an error

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried querying statuses, likes, photos, everything works fine.

But when i add a limit "?limit=100" to the end of the string, I get an error from the Response object with errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

The relevant sections of my code is below:

```
Request rq3 = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/statuses?limit=100", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                parseFeed(response, 2);
                getNext(response, 2);
            }
        });
        rq3.executeAsync();


private void parseFeed(Response response, int type) {
    try {
        Log.v("response", response.toString());
        JSONArray feedArr = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
        switch(type) {
        case 0:

            numLikes += feedArr.length();
            likesView.setText("Likes: " + String.valueOf(numLikes));
            break;
        case 1:
            numPhotos += feedArr.length();
            photosView.setText("Photos: " + String.valueOf(numPhotos));
            break;
        case 2:
            Log.v("response", response.toString());
            numStatuses += feedArr.length();
            statusesView.setText("Statuses: " + String.valueOf(numStatuses));
            break;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void getNext(Response response, final int type) {
    Request next = response.getRequestForPagedResults(Response.PagingDirection.NEXT);
    if (next != null) {
        Log.v("status", "getting next");
        next.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                parseFeed(response, type);
                getNext(response, type);
            }
        });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(next);
    }
    else {
        Log.v("status", "ended");
    }
}
```

Comment: Request(Session, String, **Bundle**, HttpMethod) not Request(Session, String) .... i'm pretty sure that this api adds  `?some_ouath_param=some_oauth_value` to the end of `/me/statuses?limit=100` and now url is f...up maybe using Bundle with key limit and value 100 will o the trick ... ps i never used graph api :P but i'm good with google.com and reading documentation ...

Comment: Yes, I've added the parameters to a Bundle and that solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Request(Session, String, Bundle, HttpMethod, Callback)
```

> **parameters**    Additional parameters to pass along with the Graph API request; parameters must be Strings, Numbers, Bitmaps, Dates, or Byte arrays.

According to the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Request/), parameters should not be part of the graph path. You are actually passing a `null` `Bundle`.

---

The right usage:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("limit", 100);

Request rq3 = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
                          "/me/statuses",                         
                          params,                         
                          HttpMethod.GET,                 
                          new Request.Callback() {
                              @Override
                              public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                  parseFeed(response, 2);
                                  getNext(response, 2);
                              }
                          }
                     );
```